# AWS Amplify REST API Lambda Function 403 {"message":"Access Denied"}

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS Amplify and for days I've been getting a `403 {"message":"Access Denied"}` error when running an API.get request to a lambda function. The ClaudWatch logs are showing that it's an unauthorized request. This was once working and if I roll back to a previous deployment in the deployment history in the staging section of the API gateway, it works. The console logs are showing that the API url are correct when compared with this URL in the staging section in API gateway. One thing to note is I'm also passing a query string parameter with the api call. CORS has also been enabled and I have deployed the API

I have configured my API gateway with a Cognito user pool authorizer. My screenshots and code are below.

[image]

[image]

```
const authorization = (await Auth.currentSession()).getIdToken().getJwtToken();
        console.log({ authorization });

        const xmlText = await API.get("AbnLookupApi", "/abnLookup", {  
            headers: {
                authorization,
            },
            queryStringParameters: {
                // acnNumber: '30656142479' 
                acnNumber: cbnNumber
            }
        }).then((result) => {
            const xml = parseXml(result);
            console.log(xml);
            const error = xml.getElementsByTagName('exceptionDescription');
            if(error.length > 0)
            {
                processErrors(error);
                return;
            }
            const orgNameElement = xml.getElementsByTagName("organisationName");
            console.log(orgNameElement[0].value); 
            setOrgName(orgNameElement[0].value)
        }).catch((e) => {
            dispatch(setError(e.message));
            console.log(e);
        }); 
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I managed to resolve this. I'm not sure exactly how but I think it was when I rolled back to a working version in API gateway and then rolled back to the latest version again.